# Communication between processor and high speed perihperal

Tags: interface, embedded, operating-system, processor, rtos

Considering that a processor runs at 100 MHz and the data is coming to the processor from an external device/peripheral at the rate of 1000 Mbit/s (8 Bits/Clockcycle @ 125 MHz), which is the best way to handle traffic that comes at a higher speed to the processor ?

Comment: This belongs on hardwareoverflow. oh wait there isn't one.

Comment: @Byron - incorrect - this is absolutely a programming question

Comment: This is really more of a 'system' question.  It requires knowledge and coordination of both the hardware and the software as a system.  Though there are a couple of good answers, you might consider posting on chiphacker.com.

Comment: You need a faster processor or special purpose hardware to do anything meaningful at that data rate. Even assuming a 32 bit processor you have just 3 clock cycles for each word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, you can't do it in software. There would be no way to sample the digital lines at a sufficient rate, or to doing anything useful with it.

You need to use a hardware FIFO buffer or memory cell. When a data burst comes in, it can be buffered in the high speed FIFO and then read out as needed by the processor.

Drop in high speed FIFO chips are surprisingly expensive (though most are dual ported). To cut cost, you would be best off using an SRAM chip, and a hardware adder to increment the address lines on incoming data.

Comment: CPLD would be a good option, especially at their current prices.

Answer (score 2):

You buffer it. Typically data from a device is written to a memory buffer (circular queue) using DMA (no cpu involved). The cpu reads from the memory buffer at a constant rate. Usually devices send data in bursts. This keeps the buffer from filling up. If there is too much data, buffer overflow.

Comment: I think you mean DMA (Direct Memory Access).  The DMA engine is a separate part of the hardware that steals memory access cycles in between the CPU accessing the memory.  So although it doesn't directly involve the CPU it may in fact impact the overall performance of the system.  And as you point out the overall memory will need to be large enough and the cpu needs to be fast enough to provide any needed processing,before the next burst is acquired.

Comment: @simon, Yes DMA is what i meant. Fixed that.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an uncommon situation for software.  semaj said the right word.  This is a system engineering issue.  Other folks have the right answer too.  If you want to look at or process that data with the 100MHz processor, it is not going to happen, dont bother trying.  You CAN look at snapshots of it or have the hardware filter out a specific percentage of it that you are looking for.  At the end of the day though it is a systems issue, what does the hardware provide, where does it put this data, what is the softwares task for this data, does it see X buffers of data come in on the goesinta, and the notify the goesouta hardware that there are X buffers ready to go?  Does the hardware examine and align the buffers so that you can look at a header, and then decide where to route the hardware?  Once you do your system engineering you will know if you can use that processor or not, and if you can use it what its job is and how to do it.

Your direct question.  What is the best way to handle it.  The best way to handle it is to have hardware (fpga, asic, etc) move it into and out of some storage device (ram of some sort probably).  Not necessarily the same ram the processor runs out of (DMA is a good thing to avoid).  The hardware is something the software can talk to but you cannot examine all of that data so dont try.  Without knowing what kind of data this is, what form, what the software looks at how much work you are willing to force the hardware to do, etc determines the rest of the answer.  If you expect a certain (guaranteed) percentage to be bad or not belong to this processor, etc have the hardware filter that out and then what is left you can process.

Networking is a good example of this, PCs have gige ports but cannot process GigE line rate data.  That is why we use switches now instead of hubs, hardware slices out a percentage of the data so the pc can handle it, the protocols take care of the data that cannot be processed by resending it later.  And the switches processors dont look at all of the data, the hardware slices it up so the software can examine just the header.  Or sometimes the software simply manages tables that drive the hardware and the hardware does all the work of processing the data.

Do your system engineering the answers will simply fall out.

Answer (score 1):

DMA (direct memory access) is possibly the solution, however, it seems unlikely that the memory bus could run faster than the processor core, so the receiving peripheral would have to accept data into a larger register than 8 bit because 125MHz could not be sustained.  For example a 16bit register would allow memory writes at 62.5MHz which may be achievable.  Also the receiving device would have to be able to accept an external clock that is both faster and asynchronous to the core clock.  Also of course the receiving peripheral must have support for DMA.

Unless you are more specific about your hardware and the communication protocol it is difficult to give anything other than a general answer.